# Query by email address Mysql C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to retrieve from mysql server but when I ask with email address it does not work. Here is my code:

```
if (!textBox3.Text.Equals(""))
{
    if (!sql.Contains("WHERE"))
    {              
        sql = sql + " WHERE Email='"+textBox3.ToString()+"'";
    }
    else
    {
        sql = sql + " AND Email='" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "'";
    }
}
```

I guess, it is a special character problem. But I've not resolved this. I think, there is a solution that formalized query but as you see, it is not useful for this struct. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Use parameterized sql

Comment: don't need to guess, insert value which not having special characters and test your application for that.

Comment: you ca try with parameter like `Email=@Email` and then add `if(sql.Contains("@Email")){ cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox3.Text);}` when you set parameter value

Comment: If you tend to use same construct, try to use StringBuilder and append strings